# Unable to connect to Postgresql via docker even after providing required network settings

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have installed postgresql on local and want to connect my docker instance to it.

The docker run command includes:

```
run: 
    IMAGE=$(IMAGE) CONFIG=$(config) docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d

local:
    @make build
    @echo "\nCreate docker container.."
    @make run config=$(config)
    @echo "\n$(GREEN)Done.$(NO_COLOR)\n"
    @echo "Try pallet at http://localhost:8080."
    @echo "and flower at http://localhost:5555."
```

---

```
POSTGRES_HOST=192.168.0.142:5432
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_CREDS=pallet:pallet
```

These are the settings from docker and an environment file, respectively.

The docker build is successful but I am getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.21.0.2", user "pallet", database "airflow", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.21.0.2", user "pallet", database "airflow", SSL off
```

I have already changed the configuration files:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'            # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                        # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min          # 1s-600s
ssl = true                              # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
                                        # (change requires restart)
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on         # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'          # (change requires restart)
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'          # (change requires restart)
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'         # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_file = ''                       # (change requires restart)
#ssl_crl_file = ''                      # (change requires restart)
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off
#row_security = on

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see "man 7 tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0                # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
```

And the lines are already added:

```
#hostssl "airflow" "pallet" '*' md5
#hostnossl "airflow" "pallet" '*' md5
host all all '*' trust
```

Yes, I did uncomment and then ran each of them in the file `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to `pg_hba.conf`

```
host all all all trust
```

or more specific if you like.

The error message shows very clear that the host ip is not allowed.

Comment: where is `pg_hba.conf` file? How do I edit it? In `docker-compose`, `Dockerfile` or manually inside the container?